# xcode view collection cell wrong size

Tags: cell, collectionview

I have a custom collection cell nib that has the size w:160 h:146. When i populate my collection view, all the elements are extremely small, like 20px * 20px.

Why does it decrease the size of my cells ? This is my code

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)IndexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";

    [collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TjansterCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell1"];


    TjansterCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:IndexPath];

    return cell;


}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the collection view flow layout is using the default size for its 'itemSize' property. Fortunately, this is easy to fix. Simply add the following code to your collection view's delegate:

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(<your width>, <your height>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where my custom size remained the standard size when I ran the app. Therefore, to solve this problem I found by manually resizing the cell in storyboard first and then entering or re-entered the custom sizes in the size inspector solved this buggy problem.
Also, I found that when you select the collection view in storyboard and select the size inspector. Here you enter the correct dimensions under Collection View Size and enter the dimensions in the Cell size text fields. This is the important part.